# Sabre api revalidate service unavailable?

Tags: rest, sabre

I am trying to use the REST Revalidate Itinerary service provided by Sabre.If you have access to the sabre developer site, you can find the details here:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/revalidate_itinerary

I am posting to api.sabre.com/v3.3.0/shop/flights/revalidate as instructed, but I am getting a 404 back with the message that "No service exists" at that URL.

Has anyone been able to get this to work, or does anyone know the correct URL?

Updated with the raw response, obtained using Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
date: Wed, 21 Feb 2018 17:05:39 GMT
EnvType: production
message-id: EogQto
singularityheader: appId=1448*ctrlguid=1516860998*acctguid=9e6c885b-de5c-4175-ac13-773e8d4b7ab2*ts=1519232739414*btid=16580*guid=5daa09fd-ca10-4c8b-b35c-968a410d211e*exitguid=1|1*unresolvedexitid=49225*tcop=1:2058128*cidfrom=171608*etypeorder=JMS*esubtype=JMS*cidto={[UNRESOLVED][49225]}*tcop=1:2058128
x-provider-instance-id: raf-darhlp010-8080
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 255
Server: Sabre Gateway

{"status":"Complete","reportingSystem":"RAF","timeStamp":"2018-02-21T17:05:39+00:00","type":"Application","errorCode":"WARN.RAF.APPLICATION","instance":"raf-darhlp010-8080","message":"No service exists for: /cto-darwin-raf/v3.4.0/shop/flights/revalidate"}
```

Here is my payload in full:

```
POST https: //api.havail.sabre.com/v3.4.0/shop/flights/revalidate?mode=live HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer T1RLAQJ940LxYe01yXkBtjZ6g6PEJkjPfxDiW51CX1eYL52BV7ZR+vuQAACw70cYo2xd9slV8ZA8cpJFXg+4qGrxxg83PFKleE3Vm7AHTbrztkg3aHccOVLazItRcJmtR/Ohz96mz    +em96HYv2n8SVBgdKTvcN1rwhBXrFsmGKY8E+LUK2wBPSQVz8kGmPW89G//EPp1igTJaaWZrJFxoq40G8SCS0HEyt3RTMNmVLtv7q0a+xuQWYJyGKpxSujRIeJzajN86YiJ7+Eck8rpyFnVOyIlKnO5fiX6C6E*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: api.havail.sabre.com
Content-Length: 1204
Expect: 100-continue

{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        "POS": {
            "Source": [
                {
                    "RequestorID": {
                        "CompanyName": {
                            "Code": "TN"
                        },
                        "Type": "1",
                        "ID": "1"
                    },
                    "PseudoCityCode": "C94H"
                }
            ]
        },
        "OriginDestinationInformation": [
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2018-03-23T08:50:00",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "LHR"
                },
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "JFK"
                },
                "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "Flight": [
                        {
                            "OriginLocation": {
                                "LocationCode": "LHR"
                            },
                            "DestinationLocation": {
                                "LocationCode": "JFK"
                            },
                            "Airline": {
                                "Operating": "VS",
                                "Marketing": "DL"
                            },
                            "ClassOfService": "B",
                            "Number": 4370.0,
                            "DepartureDateTime": "2018-03-23T08:50:00",
                            "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-03-23T13:00:00",
                            "Type": "A"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "RPH": "1"
            },
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2018-03-24T19:30:00",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "JFK"
                },
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "LHR"
                },
                "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "Flight": [
                        {
                            "OriginLocation": {
                                "LocationCode": "JFK"
                            },
                            "DestinationLocation": {
                                "LocationCode": "LHR"
                            },
                            "Airline": {
                                "Operating": "VS",
                                "Marketing": "DL"
                            },
                            "ClassOfService": "B",
                            "Number": 4373.0,
                            "DepartureDateTime": "2018-03-24T19:30:00",
                            "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-03-25T07:30:00",
                            "Type": "A"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "RPH": "2"
            }
        ],
        "TravelerInfoSummary": {
            "SeatsRequested": [
                1
            ],
            "AirTravelerAvail": [
                {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
                        {
                            "Code": "ADT",
                            "Quantity": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "PriceRequestInformation": {
                "TPA_Extensions": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it didn't like the querystring '?mode=live'. If I remove that, I get a response. We use that string in all our other REST requests to shop/flights/ but looks like it's not valid in this circumstance.

Also, thanks to Thomas for his help

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not start using the endpoint you are using. According to the https://developer.sabre.com/resources/api_versioning it gets switched to https://api.havail.sabre.com by mid of the year. I guess you already use https?

Besides that it works for me when taking the sample payload and adjusting it for real data. Can you provide your header/payload?

Comment: That is a good point about the endpoint - thank you for that. I have changed that, and also gone through my request making it as close as possible to the example. Stll no joy. I am updating my question with my request.

Comment: Should be https: //api.havail.sabre.com/v3.3.0/ instead of https: //api.havail.sabre.com/v3.4.0/

Comment: Also your flight number looks funny - should be an Integer "Number": 4370

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Fixing those two things hasn't made a difference. In other news, it transpires that this is a feature that needs switching on for our account at Sabre's end. This has been requested, and might have been the problem all along. If that turns out to be the case I'll update with that as the answer